# SQL Server Windows authentication in kubernetes

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, kubernetes, windows-authentication

Sorry I might get negatives for this small question.

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication from a kubernetes pod with a C# ASP.NET Core application.

What should the connection string be like?

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="AveenoData" 
         connectionString="data source=localhost;
                           initial catalog=NP_DB;persist security info=True; 
                           Integrated Security=SSPI;" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Or how can I add my Windows credentials to the Kubernetes pod?

Comment: Normally when the server and client run in different networks where Windows authentication is difficult I just change to normal user/pass and drop the Windows thing altogether. It just makes things simpler.

Comment: It's not the connection string. I assume you run Kubernetes on Linux which means Windows Authentication isn't available out of the box. Windows Authentication uses Kerberos though, so you need to set up Kerberos authentication between your pods and the AD Domain of the server. This is [a supported scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) because Windows clients need to be able to connect to SQL Server on Linux without hard-coding credentials.

Comment: @Alejandro no it doesn't. Throwing out the baby with the bathwater is never a good solution. Now you have to manage passwords, store them securely, change them periodically *without any support from server or OS*. Should the users have to remember yet another password now? Or should the password be stored in a file?

Comment: The official docs can be a bit long-winded. [This blog post](https://sqlsunday.com/2021/04/15/connecting-linux-using-ad-authentication/) shows that once you join the Linux host on the AD domain, all you need is to run `kinit my.name@MY-DOMAIN.LOCAL` to get a Kerberos token for the current session, after which you can connect with Integrated authentication

Comment: Create connection string with username and password.  Use Helm Secrets to keep it safe.  That means that you will have a dev environment and a production environment.  The username and password will be edited by a sys admin using Helm secrets or other k8s encryption when deployed. Welcome to Kubernetes and self-management of sensitive data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You have to manage passwords one way or another, OS assistance just changes the place for their management. Typically, in pretty much any website I came across, the DB credentials are stored in configuration files alongside it, where only a few selected administrators have access. The users, of course, remain utterly ignorant of such details, one way or another, they just need the password to their account, if any.

Comment: @Alejandro actually, no. This isn't about web sites,  it's not just OS assistance nor do you have to always manage the password. The OS *knows* the OS account so you don't need to supply it **anywhere**. Application pool accounts have no password at all, they're special service accounts that can only be used to run web sites on a server. You can also create domain-wide service accounts whose passwords are managed by the OS.

Comment: @Alejandro `in pretty much any website I came across` that's a characteristic (problem?) of those sites and environments, not of Windows authentication. In corporate sites/applications you'd find the exact opposite - domain wide service accounts. Domain admins can't go updating passwords on dozens or hundreds of applications every few months. Even if they don't rotate passwords, the *don't* have to edit dozens of different config files

Comment: @Alejandro if you have an application using multiple services on a farm you *don't* want to have to change the password on every single config file on every single server either. The entire application would be either offline or in a partially failed state while you changed the passwords one by one. You don't have to do that if you use service accounts. In a Kubernetes environment outside a domain this is handled by the *orchestrator* passing the credentials to the app using environment variables or a side-car, and restarting pods one by one automatically. Again, no statically stored passwords

Comment: @PraveenKumar do you *have* to use Windows Authentication? Or can you use Kubernetes to provide credentials, eg using Kubernetes' own [Secrets Store](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/),through Helm or another service?

Comment: @PraveenKumar are you using Linux or Windows pods? If yo use Windows, the Kubernetes docs show how to [use service accounts on a Windows pod or container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-gmsa/) or [run a pod as a specific Windows user](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-runasusername/).

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect with connection string but with active directory.
you can look at
[Configure Active Directory authentication with SQL Server on Linux containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-containers-ad-auth-adutil-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver15)
[AD(Active Directory) authentication for SQL Containers on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/ad-active-directory-authentication-for-sql-containers-on-azure/ba-p/2745659)